# Linecast not working as is should?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a a newbie in Unity3D and I'm trying to learn so this question may be inappropriate but i have an GameObject x with sphere collider AND a rigidbody and two vector3 points a and b;

In Monodevelop Watch:

```
x.collider.bound.Contains ( a ) = true
x.collider.bound.Contains ( b ) = false;
Physics.Linecast ( b, a ) = false
```

Why is this happening?

Is this an Unity bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is the collider enabled? Is the collider in the default raycast layer mask?

Comment: Yes. The collider is in the default raycast layer mask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collider's bounds are a cube. The collider itself is a sphere. Therefore, being inside the collider's bounds does not mean a point is inside the collider.